# Putting longtable caption text on subsequent pages

Tags: captions, longtable

I'm using longtable for multi-page tables in a document, and have no trouble using the standard and widely used code for headers on subsequent pages:

```
\\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\tablename} \thetable{} (Continued)} \\
```

When I run that I get the following at the top of each subsequent page, as expected:

```
Table 1.1 (Continued)
```

However, I'd like to get the rest of the text I defined in the \caption command into the header of subsequent pages as well. Thus, if I defined my caption right after the longtable command as:

```
\caption{Feasible trips for a highly variable grid} \\
```

I'd like the header on the second a subsequent pages to look like this:

```
Table 1.1: Feasible trips for a highly variable grid (Continued)
```

Maybe this is simple, but I cannot find code or documentation anywhere that describes how to do this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `longtable` package documentation, section 3 "Captions and Headings", especially `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead`: Put a `\caption` without "Continued" into the `\endfirsthead` section of your `longtable` and `\caption` with "Continued" into the `\endhead` section and voilá, you should get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `longtable` package documentation, section 3 "Captions and Headings", especially `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead`:
Put a `\caption` without "Continued" into the `\endfirsthead` section of your longtable and `\caption` with "Continued" into the `\endhead` section and voilá, you should get what you want.